# simple c++ program about calculation of percentage of user input

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
 int main()
{
    int amount; 
    int discount;
    cout<<"please enter amount : ";
    cin>>amount;

    discount = amount*(10/100);
    cout<<"the discount amount is"<<discount<<endl; 
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

i am writing simple c++ program in which i wanted to get answer of input digits entered by user the simple mathematical equation is calculating in int amount variable but its not giving a required answer its giving a 0 but the code is correct i guess.

Answer (score 2):

`10/100` is integer division, which results in `0`. Hence you multiply the amount by zero, netting zero again.

**Edit:**

In case you come from a dynamic language like JavaScript or Python, they often use implicit double variables for everything, hence this would give you the expected value. C++ has a much stronger type system, so integral division will always yield another integer. If you wanted a division of floating point values you need to use floating point literals (or cast, but in this case it's not necessary):

```
discount = amount * 10.0 / 100.0;
```

Or, if `float` is enough precision for you:

```
discount = amount * 10.0f / 100.0f;
```

Comment: +1 Floating point arithmetic is the way to go in the general case when decimal figures are involved. Alternatively, for his simple calculation he can just use integer arithmetic but skip the parentheses so that the integer quantities are the ones he wants: `discount = amount * 10 / 100;`.

Comment: thank you very much for all can you please more clear that using double data type actually taking 8 bytes if i am having big program this will surly makes my prog slow and big so for values like amount and age i can also use short in order to make my program run fast then why not i cant use int and short in this case however the values are too much small that int and short can handle this.

Comment: @Raheel What Stjepan told you is that in C++ integer arithmetics, `10 / 100` is equal to 0. Nobody forbids you from using integers, just take into account that `10 / 100`  is equal to 0 in integer arithmetics.

Comment: thank you very much @DanielDaranas i got it now its mean in int 0.1 answer will be truncated to zero due to using int data type. =) stay healthy.